# Crash for UIAlertController in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertcontroller

I got following crash report related to UIAlertController and can't reproduce the crash.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Trying to dismiss UIAlertController <UIAlertController: 0x7a740910> with unknown presenter.'

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x034dfdda ___exceptionPreprocess + 154
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03169a97 _objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x034dfd1d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
3   UIKit                               0x02268999 -[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:triggeredByPopoverDimmingView:] + 444
4   UIKit                               0x022687d8 -[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:] + 56
5   UIKit                               0x022683c4 -[UIAlertController _actionViewTapped:] + 68
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0317f771 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
7   UIKit                               0x0244b06c -[_UIAlertControllerActionView _triggerSelect] + 60
8   UIKit                               0x0244af27 -[_UIAlertControllerActionView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 187
9   UIKit                               0x023eb257 __UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 13225
10  UIKit                               0x0200471b -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1356
11  UIKit                               0x0200557f -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 769
12  UIKit                               0x01fcaaa9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
13  UIKit                               0x01fda8de __UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
14  UIKit                               0x01faf079 __UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
15  CoreFoundation                      0x034037bf ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
16  CoreFoundation                      0x033f92cd ___CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
17  CoreFoundation                      0x033f8828 ___CFRunLoopRun + 952
18  CoreFoundation                      0x033f81ab _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
19  CoreFoundation                      0x033f7fdb _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
20  GraphicsServices                    0x0564c24f _GSEventRunModal + 192
21  GraphicsServices                    0x0564c08c _GSEventRun + 104
22  UIKit                               0x01fb2e16 _UIApplicationMain + 1526
23  FantasyCricket                      0x001435ad _main + 141
24  libdyld.dylib                       0x04055ac9 _start + 1
```

I am using AlertController for iOS 8 and later.

Edit:

Sample code for displaying alert:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UIAlertController"))
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                                                   message:msg
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:nil];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];

    //other UIAlertAction here......

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title
                               message:msg
                              delegate:nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

Using also in appDelegate (by getting the current controller and presenting alert on that controller) also, Can that cause issue..?

Comment: can you paste your code here.

Comment: I'm using alert at many places in app.

Comment: but you can use breakpoint to find the line in your code  where your application get crashed.So it will be easy for us to help you then.

Comment: As I said I am not able to reproduce it, and I got the the crash only one time. Displaying from AppDelegate can cause the issue?

Comment: Error message is itself quite clear. It says it is NSInternalInconsistencyException due to the class that presented UiAlertController is now not there, possibly deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem as there is a bug in ios 8 with UIAlertController. Have a look over [this link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7577), might be helpful to you.